# Problem loading image in HTML Pop up in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, html

I am trying to load a small image along with other field in Html pop up but i am getting some problem. I tried using field calculator with Python code `"<img src=%s width='300' />" % r'!Location!'` where the 'Location' is field in the same attribute table with full address of the image to be displayed in pop up.
With this code the result returned was `<img src=u"E:\\checkpopup\\1562029949828.jpg" />` . Now when I check in the HTML pop up all the fields are shown along with picture field but without picture. After some checking when I remove that 'u' alphabet before the address of the image , the image is displayed in the HTML pop up. Now how can I avoid getting 'u' before the address?

Comment: I'm not sure what good an E: address will be on most computers, but if the location column is Unicode, you might need to encode it to UTF-8 (`'!Location!'.encode('UTF-8')`)

Comment: Thank you. It worked and i was able to display the local image in html pop up which is stored in my computer.